# Building ruby on a Raspberry "mini distro"

Tags: raspbian, software-development, software-compilation, ruby

I installed [this little disk image](https://www.linuxsystems.it/raspbian-wheezy-armhf-raspberry-pi-minimal-image/) on a 1GB SD card. I would like to run ruby within this system, which is not installed yet. I decided to use rbenv instead of RVM (I have my reasons).

My understanding is that i should first install rbenv (done), and then from within rbenv: ruby.

`rbenv install 1.8.7-p375` gives me errors about missing tools and commands, which I then try to install. Last missing command/tool was `yacc`. What is it? What big *meta package* am I missing?

Stuff I did to the bare-bones installation of my Raspberry Pi:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install git
(install rbenv)
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install subversion
apt-get install autoconf
```

Isn't there a simpler way to make sure I do have everything needed to successfully produce a valid ruby installation?

Answer (score 2):

[Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) is a tool often used together with [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) to create a language parser, which is a critical part of a code interpreter such as `ruby`.  The language (in this case Ruby) is described using a special notation understood by `yacc`, which then compiles (part of) the parser.

So yeah, you need it. There are yacc compatible tools such as [bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) that *might* be used in its place, however; if that's an easier option for you then check if `rbenv` can work with it instead.